# Function not integrable but absolute function integrable?

Tags: integration, absolute-value

I know that the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1&\text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
0&\text{if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

is not integrable. Then how would I come up with a new function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)$ is not integrable but $|g(x)|$ is integrable? First, if a function is absolutely integrable, then I think the function should be integrable.

Comment: How about $f(x)-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Then f(x) is 1/2 or -1/2. Then how would I argue that |f(x)| is integrable? And why is f(x) is integrable?

Comment: Well, what is $|f(x)|$ now? And remember, you want $f(x)$ to *not* be integrable.

Comment: $|f(x)|$ is just $\frac{1}{2}$. Right? And $f(x)$ is still piece-wise, so $f(x)$ is NOT integrable?

Comment: What integral do you mean: Riemann, Lebesgue or something else?

Comment: Riemann, presumably, since the example is Lebesgue integrable.  Of course, OP should have stated that.

Comment: "Still piece-wise" does not imply it is not integrable.  It's not (Riemann) integrable because it's discontinuous everywhere (or, if you don't want to use Lebesgue's criterion, you can calculate the upper and lower sums directly).

Answer (score 3):

What about:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1&\text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
-1&\text{if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$